# What's the purpose of Doctrine's query builder?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, query-builder

I'm wondering what exactly are the pros of using doctrine to build queries such as :

```
<?php
// $qb instanceof QueryBuilder

$qb->select('u')
   ->from('User u')
   ->where('u.id = :identifier')
   ->orderBy('u.name ASC');
   ->setParameter('identifier', 100); // Sets :identifier to 100, and thus we will fetch a user with u.id = 100
```

The only advantage i see here is data sanitizing and parameter binding, which can be easily done using PDO.

Also another example :

```
<?php
// $qb instanceof QueryBuilder

// example8: QueryBuilder port of: "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = ? OR u.nickname LIKE ? ORDER BY u.surname DESC" using Expr class
$qb->add('select', new Expr\Select(array('u')))
   ->add('from', new Expr\From('User', 'u'))
   ->add('where', $qb->expr()->orX(
       $qb->expr()->eq('u.id', '?1'),
       $qb->expr()->like('u.nickname', '?2')
   ))
   ->add('orderBy', new Expr\OrderBy('u.name', 'ASC'));
```

Is it really worth the extra dependencies are performance cost ? The above syntax seems more complicated to me than a simple string containing the query.

Answer (score 0):

It is more structural this way. It also removes DQL(or SQL) code from the PHP code that looks much better this way.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by "structural" ? Also the SQL code is still here, you could almost rebuild the whole query by concatenating all the strings. The columns for example, it's not OrderBy($table->column, ASC) but still "u.name". Same for the aliases, it is still in the form "column alias".

Comment: By saying structural I mean that you see only methods calls. There is no SQL code, there is methods call. Yes - all this is just a matter of taste. But I like more when my queries look more like ordinary object-oriented programming's constructions than strings with DQL or SQL syntax in it.